# Connector type?

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to find the connector type (see links below) for some time with out success.

The pitch is ~1.5mm.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for the name I think it is a JST connector from the ZH series (1.5mm pitch).